# Limite de tiempo, reproduccion asincrona

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy programando una app de streming de audio, todo funciona, el problema es que si una de las url esta offline, se queda cargando, me gustaría establecer un limite de tiempo, por ejemplo si en 10 segundo no ha cargado, que deje de inténtalo y lo notifique.
mi código:

```
private void BotonReproducir() {
        if (block == 0) {
            if (url != "") {
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bufering...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    block = 1;
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                        //Inicia reproducción.
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        block = 0;
                        // Lanzo la notificacion creada en el paso anterior
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select a rario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Espere a que cargue la radio anterior", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso no existe la posibilidad de definir un timeout pero para esto  puedes configurar [MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html) lo cual te propone la documentación, esto para detectar el error y realizar otra acción.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                //Realiza acción al ocurrir un error.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se pudo cargar Multimedia, intente más tarde.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return false;
            }
        });
```

> [**OnErrorListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html):
>
> Definición de interfaz de callback a invocarse cuando se ha producido
>   un error durante una operación asíncrona en el MediaPlayer.

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

`MediaPlayer` no tiene un mecanismo de timeout por defecto por lo que habria que crear uno.

El metodo `start()` pone el objeto en estado de INICIADO y para saber si ha iniciado podemos utilizar el metodo `isPlaying()`. Para emular el timeout utilizamos [`Handler#postDelayed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) para que se ejecute a los 10 segundos y validamos si esta reproduciendo. Si no lo esta, mostramos el mensaje:

```
 try {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bufering...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                 // mostramos el mensaje
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se pudo reproducir el audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
                }
            }
        }, 10000);// 10000 = 10,000 milisegundos = 10 segundos 

//...
```